# Multiple copies of a Sharepoint list view

Tags: sharepoint, listview, sharepoint-2007

We have a Sharepoint website with a different page for each of our products and another page displaying a list of all our product release dates.  You can change the view in this list so that only the release dates of a particular product are shown.

Is is possible to have a list view showing release dates of one product show up on the page dedicated to that product?  We would like to have each product page show its own release dates, but if someone updates the master list, each individual product list should be updated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use the [dataview webpart](http://ari.provoke.co.nz/archive/2007/04/17/data-view-web-part-introduction-1.aspx) to view a "master" list. You will be able to define a different filter for each webpart. With XSLT you are also able to completely customise the output of the HTML, but I prefer to use only one to avoid all the work.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to make the master list available on the product pages is to syncronize the content of the master list into a hidden list on the product pages, you could use a Event Receiver for this. This solution will require some custom code but it is pretty simple.